# trying to write an apple script that chimes every hour

Tags: applescript

I'm trying to write this script that chimes on every hour. I saved it as an application and selected the checkbox run after completion but it doesn't work. My code looks like this:

```
global chime
set chime to (path to resource "chime.mp3")
on idle
    set currenthour to hours of (current date)
    if currenthour = 0 then
        set currenthour to 12
    end if
    if currenthour > 12 then
        set currenthour to currenthour - 12
    end if
    set currentminute to minutes of (current date)
    set currentsecond to seconds of (current date)
    set currenttime to {currentminute, currentsecond} as text
    if currenttime is "" then
        repeat currenthour times
            do shell script "afplay " & (quoted form of POSIX path of chime)
        end repeat
    end if
    return 1
end idle
```

Comment: Is this just an exercise to see if you can do it? or is this meant to be functional code? I ask because AppleScript is not best-suited to this kind of task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a script app, the number you return from the `on idle` handler tells the system how long to sleep the app before the next idle invocation. You can use this set up a (loosely) accurate timer.

```
global chime, firstRun

on run
    -- I'm not sure if this is necessary, but I always use explicit run handlers in script apps.
    set chime to (path to resource "chime.mp3")
    set firstRun to true
end run

on idle
    set {currenthour, currentminute, currentsecond} to {hours, minutes, seconds} of (current date)
    
    -- don't chime when the script app is activated
    if not firstRun then
        
        -- quick mathy way to retrieve the number of chimes.
        set chimeCount to (currenthour + 11) mod 12 + 1
        repeat chimeCount times
            do shell script "afplay " & (quoted form of POSIX path of chime)
        end repeat
    else
        set firstRun to true
    end if
    
    -- calculate the number of seconds until the next hour mark and tell app to sleep until then
    return 60 * (60 - currentminute) + 60 - currentsecond
end idle
```